# Doctrine get confused when generating plural method of a field that ends with a letter "s"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

I have an rntity called **Account**, which can have many phone numbers (or **Dnis**, as I have named the related Entity ).

The definition for **Account** using yml is:

```
models\Account:
  type: entity
  table: account
    oneToMany:
      dnis:
        targetEntity: models\Dnis
        mappedBy: account
```

The problem is when I generate the entities classes with the following command:

```
doctrine orm:generate:entities
```

Since it is a OneToMany relation, the **Account** entity has a dnis collection, the problem is that the "add" method gets named as "addDni".

```
/**
 * Add dni
 *
 * @param \application\models\Dnis $dni
 *
 * @return CreditAccount
 */
public function addDni(\application\models\Dnis $dni)
{
    $this->dnis[] = $dni;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove dni
 *
 * @param \application\models\Dnis $dni
 */
public function removeDni(\application\models\Dnis $dni)
{
    $this->dnis->removeElement($dni);
}
```

I guess doctrine get confused because it thinks that the property "dnis" is a plural just because ends with a letter "s".

How can I let doctrine know that "dnis" is the actual name of the property? Or am I missing something here in the entity definition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining a `OneToMany` association.

That means that one `Account` can have many `Dnis`.
This is why `Dnis` is considered as plural, because it represents the `Many` side of the `OneToMany` association, also it's normal that doctrine generates a `addDni` method that add a given `Dnis` to the collection of `Dnis`, same for the `removeDni` that remove a given `Dnis` and for the `getDnis` that fetches the whole collection of `Dnis`.

If you need that an account can have one `Dnis`, define it as `OneToOne` and keep it as plural. You'll have a `getDnis()` and `setDnis()`.

If you doesn't like the name of your variables (i.e. `Dnis $dni`), just change it (i.e. `Dnis $dnis`).

**EDIT**

I found a quick way to avoid this unexpected behavior and I submitted [a pull request.](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/5733)
I'll let you know in case of the PR is merged, for now you can use my fix.

Comment: You mean change the name of the methods and variables manually in the generated entity class? I would like to avoid doing that, because I generate the entities with the command line tool. The association is ok, `OneToMany` is how it should be. The problem is with the name of the field. Dnis is in singular, I don't know how I should name it without loosing semantic, because that field stores in fact a DNIS record.

Comment: Yes, I mean that you should really change the name of the adder/remover's `$dni` argument. It's a common problematic, and there is not any real solution. Also, the doctrine EntityGenerator can't do it for you, because it's a specific case where `s` doesn't mean plural. So you can easily adapt the argument name without breaking anything, note that's an exception and you'll surely not face the same problem twice in your project.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for working on this. I really appreciate it. I hope it gets merged soon.